# How to remove client=firefox from google search query?

Tags: firefox

When searching for a keyword Firefox binds the "client=firefox" to the google search link like this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=test
```

How can i prevent Firefox from generating "**client=firefox-b-d**" and adding it to the search link?

i want that to be like this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=test
```

*Why i want to do this? because even if you change the user-agent properties that client=firefox is still there.*

Comment: Can I ask why you need this? (I don't understand your point about changing the user agent.)

Comment: Is it because you want to share the link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameter "client=firefox" is there so that Google will know that this
query is issued by Firefox.

This parameter is added to the search query so that Mozilla will get paid by
Google, according to its contract with Google.

The simplest method to remove this parameter is to use another search-engine
than Google.

The complicated method is to hack the Firefox release files to remove the
parameter.
You will find this hack described in the article
[Firefox Search Engine Cautions, Recommendations](https://12bytes.org/articles/tech/firefox/firefox-search-engine-cautions-and-recommendations).

Just remember that by doing this hack you are depriving Mozilla from its
rightful remuneration by Google, in spite of their nicely giving you Firefox
for free.

Comment: i didn't know firefox is getting paid by google, interesting!

Comment: See for example: https://www.cnet.com/news/google-firefox-search-deal-gives-mozilla-more-money-to-push-privacy/

Comment: When "free" software isn’t actually free...

Comment: @ElectronSurf: "free" means you are allowed to do anything you wish with the software, nobody is restricting your rights. And you can: nobody is forbidding you to remove the "client=firefox" mark for example (you wouldn't be allowed by the license to do it in "non-free" software). "Free" does not mean that nobody is never paying nobody else for it.

Answer (score 2):

When Firefox comes with the operating system, a search string is added as 'clients=canonical' or 'clients=ubuntu'.*(1)* If you install Firefox from the official site or the Mozilla PPA, it adds a search string like 'clients=firefox'. Before ff version 23, 2013, it was possible to remove these flags with the 'about: config'. But not anymore.

simple solution:

Install.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clearurls/

That is it. You won't see 'clients=ubuntu' on google search.

As mentioned [above](https://superuser.com/a/1439470/1262189), for detailed information and other solutions:

https://12bytes.org/articles/tech/firefox/firefox-search-engine-cautions-and-recommendations/

*(1)*:https://askubuntu.com/questions/784733/disable-partners-key-in-url-bar

Comment: ClearURLs is a cool tool, however if something does not work out (page not found,...), I get unsure if it might be due to an add-on, so I need to disable it and retry, that's why I do not like this solution that much.

Answer (score 1):

- Install [Search Engines Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-engines-helper/)
- Add a new search engine
- type "https://www.google.com/search?q=%s" into "SEARCH URL" (or your local domain e.g. [google.co.uk](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%25s) or [google.de](https://www.google.de/search?q=%25s))
- remove old search engine

More infos: https://12bytes.org/articles/tech/firefox/firefox-search-engine-cautions-and-recommendations/